# Prisma - Cannot find module 'ps-node' error

Tags: graphql, prisma

I am using  windows 10 OS, and I have started learning prisma.
I have successfully installed prisma version 1.34.8 using npm.

when I  execute  "prisma init projectname" , it throws

!    'MODULE_NOT_FOUND': Cannot find module 'ps-node' error.

Any idea what could be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentioned ps-node module was not there , to fix the issue , installed ps-node node module globally.

```
npm i -g ps-node
```